# How to make tiny grids on image using jquery/photoshop

Tags: jquery, css, photoshop

I want to make grids on photo for my website background. sample website for this: http://www.thebullittagency.com/. I want background with same as it is in website. I have searched lot on google. But still, I haven't found. please, help me for this. Thanks.

Comment: Seems clearly spam, question just points to an external url with no explanation about the problem whatsoever.

Comment: @moonwave99, I want a image looks like in website background: http://www.thebullittagency.com/. grid/checkerboard/strip on images. if you zoom the website, you will see grid on image properly. I don't know how to achive this. i tried some step with google resource but i failed. So, help me to achived this grid/checkerboard on images either using jquery or photoshop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create checker board transparent image in photoshop, where black pixels are actually black and white — transparent.

After that you can add background image like:

```
html {
    background: black url('background.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And add grid to `body`, like this:

```
body {
     background: url('grid.png') top center;
}
```

Comment: here is an example of patter img -http://www.thebullittagency.com/skins/bullit/images/dale.png

Comment: @Evgeniy I think, in website, jquery is used for this dale.png. i dont know how to decode it. is there any way to create with photoshop or jquery. Thanks for help.

Comment: Try this: http://citrusmoon.typepad.com/photos/uncategorized/cbfill.gif

Comment: @user3068748 decode png? its just an image, save it and open in Photoshop.